# Angular4 json data assign to variables

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to put values in variables to use it in html part but non of the solutions is working:

```
GetUserData(){
    this.userService.GetUserDetails().subscribe(data=>{
      if(Array.isArray(data))
        this.user=data;
        console.log(this.user);
    });
  }
```

This sets user variable and I am trying to access like this:

```
{{ user.ParamValue }}
```

But it shows nothing in result.

I have data like

```
[{"acname":"test2","email":"test2@gmail.com","mobile":"+xxxxxxxxxx"}]
```

The data I receive will always be a single row, so there no use of iterating like ngfor. I just like to get the value from it.

when I access this : {{ user.acname }} It shows user. However, it is showing error in console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ProfileComponent.html:61)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14377)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13513)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:13816)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13509)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:13790)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13514)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
```

[image]

Comment: Since, it is a single row, how about `this.user = data[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the index, data is still an Array.

```
GetUserData(){
    this.userService.GetUserDetails().subscribe(data=>{
      if(Array.isArray(data)) {
          this.user=data[0]; // since returns always returns a single object in the array.
      }
      console.log(this.user);
    });
}
```

Then use like:

```
{{ user.acname }}
```

Comment: Please note, I have no Angular background, have to handle this as one of my frontend developer is left.

Comment: That's no problem, the right thing to do would be to return an object itself if the array would always contain one object.

Comment: The error means, you are trying to access a mobile property of an Object which didn't get defined. Looking at line no. 61 of the `ProfileComponent.html` may help

Comment: I defined user in export class, assigned data as you suggested  this.user=data[0]; then simply trying to access user.acname, user.mobile. Previously, the error was on user.acname, when I commented out it switched to user.mobile. However, it is showing data properly in front.

Comment: what do you see when you do: `{{user | json}}` ?

Comment: { "acname": "test2", "email": "test2@gmail.com", "mobile": "+xxxxxxxxxx" }

Comment: The first element is throwing error, if I remove html  {{user.acname}} error comes to {{user.mobile}} else it is at user.acname

Comment: It's strange, did you do `{{user | json}}` at the same place where you are doing `{{user.acname}}`? It seems, somewhere in your code, `user` is getting undefined.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly, let's change the name if the variable. might be it is conflicting somewhere.

Comment: Still the same problem, but still data is getting fetched.

Comment: I don't think variable name confilct is a problem, do one thing, keep `{{user | json}}, {{user.acname}} , {{user.mobile}}` all in your template, also keep your console open, do you see getUserData() fired again?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't think I would be able to debug any further without looking into the actual project.

Comment: very strange, I did in component.ts like this this.userprofile=data[0];
        this.acname=this.userprofile.acname;
        this.mobile=this.userprofile.mobile;
        this.email= this.userprofile.email;

Comment: and then used variables like this {{ acname }}, this stopped error. normally when we iterate. we define it in html file with let. this is missing in my case. is there the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.user=data;
this.user = JSON.parse(this.user);
```

JSON.parse function help you transform JSON string to object

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.